# Axis-Aligned Bounding Boxes vs Bounding Ellipse

Tags: algorithm, 2d, collision-detection, physics

Why is it that most, if not all collision detection algorithms today require each 2D body to have an AABB for the use in the broad phase only?

**It seems to me like simply placing a circle at the 2D body's centroid, and extending the radius to where the circle encompasses the entire body would be optimal.** This would not need to be updated after the body rotates and broad overlap-calculation would be faster to. Correct?

**Bonus:**
Would a bounding ellipse be practical for broad phase calculations also, since it would better represent long, skinny shapes? Or would it require extensive calculations, defeating the purpose of broad-phase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bounding boxes are represented by linear inequality constraints while circles and ellipses need quadratic inequality constraints. One can work with both, but the linear case, as always, is much simpler to solve algorithmically (it only involves a matrix multiplication). If the bounding boxes are aligned with the world coordinate axes then all the checks look like `xa - xb > dxa + dxb`, `ya - yb > dya + dyb` and `za - zb > dza + dzb`, where `d$i$j` is the dimensions of the bounding box around object `$j` in the `$i$` direction.

Ellipse collisions detection *is* being done, however. The math is significantly harder and the implementation and computational effort might not be worth the savings. In any case, I searched Google scholar for "ellipse collision detection" and at least two papers on the first page seemed to be exactly on this topic: http://hub.hku.hk/bitstream/10722/47091/1/121854.pdf?accept=1 and ftp://crack.seismo.unr.edu/downloads/russell/doven_2005_neighbor_list_collision_driven_MD_II.PDF

Answer (score 1):

> Why is it that most, if not all collision detection algorithms today
> require each 2D body to have an AABB for the use in the broad phase
> only?

A sphere is only really a good approximation if the object being approximated is round-ish. In the general case, a bounding sphere ends up being much bigger than the object being approximated. Imagine a long rectangle. Even if the rectangle is rotated, an AABB provides a tighter approximation than a sphere.
A sphere overlap test is cheap, but so is an AABB overlap test.

> It seems to me like simply placing a circle at the 2D body's centroid,
> and extending the radius to where the circle encompasses the entire
> body would be optimal.

To provide the best fit using a sphere, the sphere would need to be offset from the object's centroid. The object's centroid only provides the best fit for symmetrical objects.
Finding the best fit for arbitrary objects seems to be a non-trivial problem. See here: [How to compute the smallest bounding sphere enclosing other bounding spheres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9063453/how-to-compute-the-smallest-bounding-sphere-enclosing-other-bounding-spheres)

> This would not need to be updated after the body rotates and broad
> overlap-calculation would be faster too.

Only with a centroid-based approach (unless you precalculate the offset, store it somewhere and transform it by the object's position and rotation, whenever it moves), which as already mentioned doesn't provide the tightest fit. Since the fit usually isn't tight, your broadphase doesn't filter out many objects, and you end up wasting more time doing more expensive checks.

> Would a bounding ellipse be practical for broad phase calculations
> also, since it would better represent long, skinny shapes?

Ellipsoids are very difficult to handle mathematically and any intersection tests with ellipsoids would far outweigh the benefits of the tighter fit they provide.
There is a special case however: Axis-aligned ellipsoids.
If your ellipsoid is a sphere that can only be stretched along X, Y or Z (or a combination thereof), instead of along any axis (or stretched along X, Y or Z and then rotated), there is a trick:
If you divide an ellipsoid's radii by themselves, you end up with a unit sphere.
If you do the same to the object being checked against the ellipsoid, you end up with a unit sphere vs X test.

**Here's an example of an algorithm that checks if an axis-aligned ellipsoid overlaps an AABB:**

1. You divide the ellipsoid's position by the ellipsoid's radii. We'll call the new position `position_es` (es = ellipsoid space).
2. You divide the AABB's min and max coordinates (or whatever representation you use) by the ellipsoid's radii. We'll call the new AABB `aabb_es`.
3. You check `aabb_es` against the unit sphere positioned at `position_es`.

The above algorithm is the idea behind swept ellipsoid collision detection presented in the following paper:
"Improved Collision detection and Response" by Kasper Fauerby: https://peroxide.dk/papers/collision/collision.pdf