# How to compute the smallest bounding sphere enclosing other bounding spheres

Tags: math, collision-detection

I'm looking for an algorithm which someone has access to that will compute the smallest bounding sphere that encloses a set of other bounding spheres. I have thought about this for a while and have come up with some initial solutions, but I don't believe these are necessarily the most accurate or the least computationally expensive (fastest).

### First Thought

My first solution is the simplest naive one, which is to average out the sphere centers to get the center point, and then compute the maximum distance from the calculated center to each sphere's center plus its radius, as the radius. So pseudo code goes like:

```
function containing_sphere_1(spheres)
  center = sum(spheres.center) / count(spheres)
  radius = max(distance(center, spheres.center) + radius)
  return Sphere(center, radius)
end
```

However I get the feeling that it isn't that computationally cheap, nor is it quite accurate since the resulting sphere could be quite larger than it needs to be.

### Second Thought

My second thought is to use an iterative algorithm to compute the minimal bounding sphere. It is computed by successively testing another sphere, if the tested sphere is inside the bounds, then nothing is done, otherwise a new bounding sphere is computed from the two spheres available. The new bounding sphere has a center that is half way between the vector between the two centers if it was extended to the spheres surfaces, and the radius is the half the length of that line (from the new center to either sphere's surface).

```
function containing_sphere_2(spheres)
  bounds = first(spheres)
  for each sphere in spheres
    if bounds does not contain sphere
      line = vector(bounds.center, sphere.center)
      extend(line, bounds.radius)
      extend(line, sphere.radius)
      center = midpoint(line)
      radius = length(line) / 2
      bounds = Sphere(center, radius)
    end
  end
  return bounds
end
```

Initially I thought that this would be the way to go, since it is iterative and seems fairly logically consistent, however after doing some reading, most notably the article "Smallest enclosing disks (balls and ellipsoids)" by Emo Welzl I'm not not so sure.

### Welzl's Algorithm

As I understand it the basis of this algorithm is that the minimum bounding sphere over a set of points in 3 dimensions can be determined by at most 4 points (which are on the surface of the enclosing sphere). So the algorithm takes an iterative approach by selecting 4 points, and then testing other points to see if they're inside or not, if they aren't a new bounding sphere is constructed featuring the new point.

Now the algorithm deals strictly with points, but I think it can be applied to deal with spheres, the main complication being accounding for the radius when constructing the enclosing sphere.

### Back to the Question

So what is the 'best', as in least computationally expensive, algorithm that creates a minimal bounding sphere for a set of given spheres?

Is one of these I have described here the answer? Some pseudo code or the algorithm would be great.

Comment: Seems like your naive approach could be made to work if you used a weighted centroid (by radius) rather than a pure centroid.  That is, the center of the bounding sphere should be closer to the center of a big sphere than a small one.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think the naive approach will work, http://hacksoflife.blogspot.com/2009/01/randomized-bounding-spheres.html seems to indicate that there are plenty of counter examples where it breaks down. It will create an enclosing sphere but not necessarily the minimal one.

Comment: [This 2008 paper by Thomas Larsson](http://www.ep.liu.se/ecp/034/009/ecp083409.pdf) has a useful bibliography of bounding sphere algorithms (for collections of points, not collections of spheres).

Comment: I'm no mathematician (and should probably just follow this with interest), but... might it be worth drawing a bounding *box* around the spheres then drawing a bounding circle around that? I guess it's still a lot of calculations to size the box but wouldn't it simplify calculating the origin move on each iteration? also, it still wouldn't be minimal necessarily but would be more minimal than your option 1 with a fixed origin. Just a thought...

Comment: @wmorrison365 A pathalogical case for that would be just a single sphere, since you'd create a box around it, and then a sphere around the box, thus the enclosing sphere would be quite larger than necessary. Though the box solution would create a smaller enclosing sphere in option 1's pathological case (lots of spheres in a cluster with one far outside it).

Comment: @Daemin Yeah, I'd realised that. I wonder if you could do the inner and outer boundary (as in, one inside the square, one surrounding) and then binary-section (cut) the distance between these to see at what point all spheres are completely bounded. The origin would at least be in place. Must admit, unlikely to be optimal. Interesting problem!

Comment: It turns out that Welzl's Algorithm doesn't work for spheres, see my thesis at http://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/emo/DoctThesisFiles/fischer05.pdf, p. 93 for a counterexample. However, as stated in the answer by @hardmath, a very fast C++ implementation is available in [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/Bounding_volumes_ref/Class_Min_sphere_of_spheres_d.html).

Comment: Hats off to Welzl’s minimum bounding sphere algorithm. I wish I'd thought of it. - Jack Ritter.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The step from enclosing points to enclosing spheres is non-trivial, as the [discussion of Welzl's algorithm (which works to enclose points)](http://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/emo/DoctThesisFiles/fischer05.pdf) in K. Fischer's thesis explains, "Smallest enclosing ball of balls".  See Sec. 5.1.

Chapter 4 presents the "enclosing points" material, then Chapter 5 presents "enclosing spheres".

The algorithm described in Fisher's thesis has been implemented [in the CGAL package](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/Bounding_volumes_ref/Class_Min_sphere_of_spheres_d.html) since release 3.0, if you are just looking for an implementation.

Comment: Thank you very much for the link to the article, it's quite a read and so looks quite comprehensive.

Comment: Just to complement your very accurate answer: the CGAL implementation offers a floating-point and exact-arithmetic implementation for the case of the minsphere _of spheres_. You do not have to use all of CGAL, just extract the required headers and it will work. – For the case of the minsphere _of points_, there is a C++ library available at https://github.com/hbf/miniball.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a fast, near optimal approach based on Ritter's algorithm 
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounding_sphere :

For each sphere, find its min/max x/y/z points. Throw these 6 points into a bucket. When you've done all N spheres, you'll have a bucket of 6N points. Find a bounding sphere for these using any of the known algorithms.

The bounding sphere you get will very likely be a little too small, regardless of algorithm. You could then do the 2nd pass of Ritter's method, but using the backsides of the spheres as the points to test. 'Backside' meaning pt on sphere farthest from current bnd sphere's center. If a sphere's backside pt is outside current bnd sphere, grow bnd sphere to include it.

In addition to the 6 extrema pts, you could initially include the 8 corners of the inscribed cube:

( [+/-]kR, [+/-]kR, [+/-]kR ), where k=sqrt(3)/3. This gives 14 pts that are fairly well-distributed, geodesically.